# RAMPS 1.6 VCC and 5 V jumper issues

Tags: troubleshooting, ramps

This is a bizarre issue.

Everything was working fine until a month ago. I upgraded to RAMPS 1.6 after my 1.4 board decided it wanted to go to the big chip in the sky. I ordered a kit to replace the 1.4 and the 2560. Everything was working fine. I notice my prints are quite a bit better. I then do a complete overhaul of the printer. New rods, bearings, belts, and a new Y-axis motor. Another test print and it honestly is the best print I have ever done.

What the heck, I'll add auto bed leveling. I install the BLTouch. Plug it in and no power (in my defense, I forgot about the VCC to 5 V jumper). So I find the new location of the jumper location and per every diagram I found, it is the two pins closest to the E0 motor connection. No problem. I power down, put the jumper on and...

I released the magic smoke from the 2560.

So I order another 2560. I check all the connections, connectors, pinouts, crimps, and do a full assessment. Everything looks good, everything is crimped correctly, the wires are in the right positions, so I turn it on and nothing happens. Good, I unplug it and put the jumper across VCC to 5 V and...

The magic smoke monster appears again.

Fine, I order another 2 boards. While I am at it, I order another RAMPS 1.6. New boards arrive and I swap out the 2560, this time I use another new 1.6 board and 2560. The only wires I connect are the power wires on the ramps board.

I turn the power on without the jumper. I measure voltage on VCC as 4.95 V. I confirm the 5 V pin has 0 V. I plug a jumper on VCC to 5 V again and...

Another magic smoke monster...

So I am thinking that it is a manufacturing issue. The only constant through the whole thing is that the 2560 boards have been from the same manufacturer. I know that this can be done as there are posts about it. I am seeking the forums opinion however. I do have 2 different 2560 boards coming.

I should also add that I dug out a spare 1.4 board, and that is working fine with the BLTouch and a new 2560 board installed albeit very slowly though.

Comment: Stop ordering obsolete tech and get a SKR 1.4. Are you sure your BLTouch wiring is correct? Might be a short on the 5V rail to ground.

Comment: @allen476 I had the same problem when I started with printers and limit switches, so the main problem is the voltage sensing, so if the sensing is set to 0V but you have 5V will appear that smoke, if the sensing is set to 5V but you have 0V the smoke will appear. All my sensors are set to 0V to avoid short cuircuits. Remember the board has + and - sensing as option while wiring. :) Good look, I will change also to 1.6 one of my printers, has a better look and heat sinks.

Comment: @towe I checked the servo pins and in fact it is shorted between +  and -. I wonder if I could just pick up 5v from the vcc pin only since I just want to power the bltouch.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a [warning](https://reprap.org/wiki/RAMPS_1.6#Warning) in the RepRap wiki regarding the same issue and checked my RAMPS 1.6 and found out I had the same issue.

In order to address the matter I de-soldered the J5 connectors and scratched the left side of +5 V pin as well as the bottom left corner of ps-on pin in order to disconnect the +5 V pin and rail from ground. I kept scratching lightly and checked whether the short was gone with a multi-meter in continuity mode until the beeping stopped.

I used the photo provided by RepRap showing where the short usually occurs along with the pads diagram file [R6.PcbDoc](https://github.com/bigtreetech/ramps-1.6/blob/master/Ramps1.6/hardware/R6.PcbDoc) from the GitHub repo which I opened using [Altium's online viewer link](https://www.altium.com/viewer) as I didn't have it installed on my machine.

[image: Photo of a RAMPS board where a short usually occurs]

I hope anyone reading this finds it useful.